# Horizontal dotted line using drawables in android java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-drawable

I want to create a horizontal dotted lien for my android java application. I have created a drawable file and used it inside the view tag on my page. But the line is not showing in the page. Code is given below. Please help!!!

Given below is the files created in drawable.

```
    android:shape="line">
    <stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#000000"
    android:dashWidth="4dp"
    android:dashGap="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

Given below is my fragment.xml

```
                android:id="@+id/line1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:drawable="@drawable/line_seperator_dotted"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/compartmentHeader" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Some weird behavior, because wrap_content doesn't work with line shape. Your stroke width is 2dp, and it is meaning, the height of your view should be 3+ dp.

So if you have a line with 5dp height, Your view must be higher than 5 (6 or more).

Or you can add size block to your drawable file and use wrap_content in your views

```
 <size android:height="5dp"/>
```